# Why can I specify a length in Curl.squeeze?

Tags: curl

[IRI](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/501e9493bc0cbd1ef1b3e0df6da39efb8ef4083d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/hash/Curl.java#L89),
[iota.lib.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/49cec7296cb179a1c83b4b1fbb4c3fa129ca9f8f/lib/crypto/curl/curl.js#L78),
[ccurl](https://github.com/iotaledger/ccurl/blob/94d74a492a7ff9494c73b7be2dcf80f3ce4d453f/src/lib/curl.h#L15),
[Pyota](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/blob/3f452a627233d413269381970058780a09215d64/iota/crypto/pycurl.py#L116)

---

I thought the length of a Curl hash was always **81 trytes or 243 trits**.

Also, does the length have to be a multiple of something or can it be any number?

Are different lengths used anywhere in IOTA?